# Is there a Notepad++ RegEx to remove everything but digits and spaces?

Tags: regex, notepad++, spaces, digits

Is there a RegEx to remove everything but digits and spaces in Notepad++?

I know there is one that removes only digits but i dont need that.

PS: I do not want the lines to be removed

Example:

```
11234123 alex-james
1412412 mmafsmasdas
```

After regex:

```
11234123
1412412
```

Comment: [^\d ]* - then replace with an empty tring.

Comment: it works but i'd like to not remove the lines with the digits

Comment: @AndrewJetun The code below works . Give it a green tick!!!

Answer (score 1):

As the pattern use `[^\d ]+`. Almost what *Poul Bak* proposed, but change `*` into `+`, i.e. the sequence of chars to match should be **non-empty**.

There is no point in searching for an empty string and replace it with another empty string.

Comment: it works but i'd like to not remove the lines with the digits

Comment: @AndrewJetun: What's problem with this answer? It does what you want, doesn't it?

Comment: My solution does not remove lines with digits. The idea is: 1. Display the *Find* screen (Ctrl/F). 2. Select *Replace* tab. 3. Enter the regex into *Find what* field. 4. *Replace with* field leave empty. 5. Select *Regular expression* radio button. 6. Click *Find Next* to find the first match. 7. Click *Replace All*. 8. After replacement click *Close*.

Answer (score 0):

correction:
try this:

```
([^0-9| ]+)
```

this will surely work!!!

open the file in notepad++ press `CTRL+H` check  the box with search mode regular expression and put in the above regex and click replace all 
[image: test image]

Comment: Why do you add parenthesis? Why do you separate `0-9` and space in 2 character class? How do you use this regex? They want to remove every character that is not digit or space. How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Toto corrected!!!

Comment: @Andrew Jetun its wokring right !!!!! give it a green tick. community will get help!!!

Comment: Try this ...... find what: `[^\d\n]*`   and replace all with: `nothing`   this won't remove lines as intended .....